# How to center ggplot figure in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Is there a way to center the "Open Tray" figure in the bottom row?

I am trying to use `sfplot <- ggarrange(Cf, Ff, Of, labels = c("A", "B", "C"))`, but obviously it won't automatically center it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `patchwork` package, you could use:

```
library(patchwork)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) + geom_point()
a + a + a + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A') +
  plot_layout(
  design = "AABB
            #CC#")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `ggarrange`, then you can nest each row of plots within another `ggarrange` (though this is obviously more verbose than just using `patchwork`):

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

Cf <- Ff <- Of <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) + geom_point()

sfplot = ggarrange(ggarrange(Cf, Ff, ncol = 2, labels = c("A", "B")), 
                   ggarrange(NULL, Of, NULL, ncol = 3, labels = c("", "C", ""), widths = c(1,2,1)), 
                   ncol = 1)
```

**Output**

[image]